# can anyone give me this missing respository location

Tags: gradle

gradle Could not resolve org.cloudfoundry cloudfoundry-client-lib 0.8.4
 with this:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  mavenRepo url :'http://repo.springsource.org/release'
  mavenRepo url:'http://repo.springframework.org/milestone/'
}
dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:1.8.6'
    compile 'org.cloudfoundry:cloudfoundry-client-lib:0.8.4'
}
```

i dunno enough about where to find the cloudfoundry-client-lib as it must have moved.
could anyone please give me the proper repo name ?
many thanx

Answer (score 0):

The correct repository is `http://repo.springsource.org/milestone`, not `http://repo.springframework.org/milestone`.